# how do i go about implementing In-Game currency?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults

I need to know how i can go about implementing In-game currency? via NSUserdefaults. I have a ball that hits a coin.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let collision = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    if collision == PhysicsCategory.Ball1 | PhysicsCategory.coin { 
        self.runAction(Gsound)
        coinNode++
    }
}

func Coin(){
    coin.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2 , y: self.frame.height / 4.5)
    coin.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
    self.addChild(coin)

    coinValuelbl.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 4)
    coinValuelbl.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    coinValuelbl.fontSize = 150
    coinValuelbl.text = "\(coinValue)"
    self.addChild(coinValuelbl)
}
```

I also need to know how I save the coinValue after I exit the game and come back so that I can add on to it when ever I collect more coins.

Comment: You need to search here for how to use `UserDefaults` there are TONS of examples. Just save the increased quantity of coins to `UserDefaults.standard` in your hit collision, and then load from the same place when you are making your coin... probably in `didMoveToView`. UserDefaults saves these things even after you exit the game. It is your solution :)

Comment: @Fluidity Thank you this worked great!!